# Create a moving plot along a parametric plot using Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphics3d, parametric-functions

I have been looking through Manipulate examples and haven't been able to create a working plot yet. I have a parametric plot defined:

```
Clear[f,x,y,t, surfaceplot]
{x[t_], y[t_]} = (t/2) {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
f[x_, y_] = 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2);
surfaceplot2 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 6Pi}, {y, 0, 6Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
```

I am trying to create a point that moves along the plot from 0 to 6Pi using manipulate. I'm trying to adapt this code:

```
 Manipulate[ 
     ParametricPlot3D[ {x[t], y[t], f[x[t],y[t]]}, {t, 0, 6Pi}, 
         PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
         Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> .05, Point[{x[t],y[t] }]}], 
     {{anotherT, 0}, 0, 6 Pi, Pi/64} ]
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

That won't work because `Epilog` yields 2D graphics primitives, so you can't have plot a moving 3D point using `Epilog`. Instead, make a separate `Graphics3D` object and `Show` both of them. So, for instance defining

```
parPlot = ParametricPlot3D[
  {x[t], y[t], f[x[t], y[t]]}
  , {t, 0, 6 Pi}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
 ];
```

we can make

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  parPlot
  , Graphics3D[ {Red, PointSize -> 0.02, Point[{x[tp], y[tp], f[x[tp], y[tp]]}] } ]
 ]
 , {tp, 0, 6 Pi, Pi/64}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Probably cleaner:

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2);
pos[t_] := {##, f@##} & @@ (t/8 {Cos[t], Sin[t]})

Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
         Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity@.5, Boxed -> False],
  ParametricPlot3D[pos@t, {t, 0, 6 Pi}],
  Graphics3D@{Red, PointSize -> .05, Point@pos@t}],
{t, 0, 6 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! This deserves the accept.